# What meta information is gathered during "the loop" survey hosted by SurveyMonkey?

Tags: support, the-loop

One aspect that I completely missed when taking "the loop" some weeks ago: the corresponding service ([SurveyMonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com)) does use cookies to track various pieces of information.

That could be IP addresses, time spent, but theoretically also stuff like browser version, operating system, ... you know, the kind of information that is sometimes used to compute a "finger print" of the computer used for browsing.

My questions to Stack Exchange Inc.:

- What "meta" information is available to you?
- How is that information used? Are you for example matching IP addresses of people taking the survey with IP addresses of users on your network?

Comment: SurveyMonkey does indeed track browser version, see [here](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/About-the-cookies-we-use) for some more info. They also use cookies to uniquely identify survey takers.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339203/is-the-loop-covered-by-sos-privacy-and-gdpr-policies

Comment: I'd like to think they've considered these aspects and have a clear answer but the complete lack of an answer on the question linked by @MarkBeadles makes it doubtful. So I'm doubtful you'll get an answer anytime soon even though this is an important question.

Comment: @Script47 I agree, and honestly that is again something where the actions respectively the silence by SE Inc doesn't spark joy. Being clear about such details is really basic housekeeping these days. Well, at least for companies that are really serious about working with a global user community.